# is it allowed to have nesting Induction?

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, induction

I am trying to prove a graph, whose subgraphs all have a minimum degree $\le d$ where $d\ge1$, is $(d+1)$-colorable by induction.

For the base case, I need to show for $d=1$, the graph is 2-colorable, but I find I need to use induction again on the number of vertices to prove the base case statement.

Can we have induction inside the base case of an induction?

Comment: The base of induction is just a normal statement. It can be proved by induction, no problem. But in your case, you are trying to show that if the *minimal* degree is 1, then the graph is 2-colorable. It seems wrong. Are you sure it is "minimal" and not "maximal"?

Comment: Yes, d is the upper bound for minimum degree in every subgraph, not the entire graph, so I guess $d\ge min(deg(G))$.

Comment: "upper bound for minimum degree in every subgraph"=maximal degree of the graph.

Comment: If it is "max degree", then you do not need induction to prove the base. Also the statement is true for $d=0$ too.

Comment: @markvs I don't think this is correct. Take a star with $n$ leaves. Then the maximal degree is $n$, but every subgraph has minimum degree upper bounded by $1$ because every subgraph is a tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the base case, you do not need induction.

Hint: When all subgraphs $G$ have minimum degree at most 1, $G$ cannot include a cycle subgraph (why?).  This means that $G$ is a in special class of graphs (which one?) that is always 2-colorable (how?).